# Wordpress Menu Customizer

Tags: menus, theme-customizer

I am working on a theme where I would like to allow users to specify additional options for nav menu items.

Out of the box, Users can just specify css classes that are applied to LI elements in a nav menu. However, I want to allow to specify css classes for links too.

I have looked at different options. I could use the options framework or I could use the customizer API without any plugin dependency. My problem with both of those approaches is that I am required to introduce a new customization menu section that deals with menus. I dont want to do that, because there already is the menu customizer in the backend. All I want to do is to add one more option for link css classes.

So far I have not found a way to hook into wordpress' own customizer without the risk of breaking when WP gets upgdated.

Can anybody point me into the right direction how I could approach this problem?

thanks.

Comment: Why are you afraid of WordPress updates? Hooks will not go with the WordPress update.

Comment: Hey prosti, thats true. With "breaking" i meant editing the original menu editor. I did not mean that hooks are going to break. I should have made myself more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this two ways.

1. Add new section to existing `nav_menus` **panel** and then add your controls to the section:

---

```
$wp_customize->add_section('my_section', array(
    'title'    => 'My options',
    'panel' => 'nav_menus'
));
$wp_customize->add_setting('my_setting', array(
    'type'              => 'theme_mod',
    'settings'          => 'my_section',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_my_setting'
));
$wp_customize->add_control('my_control', array(
    'label'   => 'My option',
    'section' => 'my_section',
    'type'    => 'text'
));
```

2. Add new controls to existing `menu_locations` **section**:

---

```
wp_customize->add_setting('my_setting', array(
    'settings'          => 'menu_locations',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_my_setting'
));

$wp_customize->add_control('my_control', array(
    'label'   => 'My Option',
    'section' => 'menu_locations',
    'type'    => 'text'
));
```

If I were you I would choose first solution because it makes Customizer more cleaner but it depends on your needs. I hop it will help

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I've already tried to add my options to the 'nav_menus' panel like you suggested. Unfortunately I could not get it to work. Might there be a priority issue? The options wont appear for some reason.